# Complex Functions: Calculate $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{r\cos{t}}\cos{(r\sin{t}+t)} dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Please help by telling me if my logic is correct. Thank you

Calculate the above integral.
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{r \cos t}\cos{(r \sin{t}+t)}~dt$$

Note: 
$$\mathbb{R}(z) = r \cos{t}$$
$$\mathbb{I}(z) = r \sin{t}$$

substituting the above then
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}\cos{(\mathbb{I}(z)+t)}~dt = $$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}\left[\cos{(\mathbb{I}(z)} \cos{t}-\sin{\mathbb{I}(z)}\sin{t}\right] dt =$$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}\left[\frac{e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}+e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}}{2} \cos{t}-\frac{e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}-e^{-i\mathbb{I}(z)}}{2}\sin{t}\right]dt =$$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}\left[\frac{e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}+e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}}{2} \cos{t}-\frac{e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}-e^{-i\mathbb{I}(z)}}{2}\sin{t}\right]dt = $$
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}\left[e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}\cos{t} + e^{-i\mathbb{I}(z)}\cos{t} \right] - e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}\left[e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}\sin{t} - e^{-i\mathbb{I}(z)}\sin{t} \right] dt =$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \left[e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}\cos{t} + e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}e^{-i\mathbb{I}(z)}\cos{t} \right] - \left[e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}e^{i\mathbb{I}(z)}\sin{t} - e^{\mathbb{R}(z)}e^{-i\mathbb{I}(z)}\sin{t} \right] dt =$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{\mathbb{R}(z)+i\mathbb{I}(z)} \cos{t} + e^{\mathbb{R}(z)-i\mathbb{I}(z)} \cos{t}-e^{\mathbb{R}(z)+i\mathbb{I}(z)} \sin{t}+e^{\mathbb{R}(z)-i\mathbb{I}(z)} \sin{t}~dt =$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{z} \cos{t} + e^{\bar{z}} \cos{t}-e^{z} \sin{t}+e^{\bar{z}} \sin{t}~dt =$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{z}\left( \cos{t}-\sin{t} \right) + e^{\bar{z}}\left( \cos{t}+\sin{t} \right) dt =$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{re^{it}}\left( \cos{t}-\sin{t} \right) + e^{re^{-it}}\left( \cos{t}+\sin{t} \right) dt =$$
now...is it right to say that because $\cos~\&~\sin$ are both bound above by 1. we can say that
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{re^{it}}\left( \cos{t}-\sin{t} \right) + e^{re^{-it}}\left( \cos{t}+\sin{t} \right) dt \leq \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 2e^{re^{it}}dt = 0$$

via the Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: The title seems different

Comment: The title does not fit to the exercise!

Comment: my apologies..i meant sin

Comment: i've fixed it, again. many apologies and thanks for pointing that out. On the other hand, is the rest of it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate the value if the integral by just finding its bound. You need his friend:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{r \cos t}  \cos(r\sin t + t)  dt + i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{r \cos t} \sin(r \sin t + t)  dt = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{r\cos t + i r\sin t + it} dt= \int_0^{2\pi} e^{re^{it}}e^{it}dt$$

This integral is zero.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: From here i would substitute $z = re^{it}$ which would give me $$\oint \frac{e^{z}e^{it}}{rie^{it}} = \frac{1}{ri} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}e^{z} dz = 0$$ yes? 
but for my own learning, 
why is it valid to just add the imaginary part? where is this coming from? its convenient i agree but i dont see where it's coming from.

Further the hint given was to use Cauchy theorem for $e^{z}$ i assume that's Cauchy's theorem for simply connected domains rather then say, Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Lastly. Thank you for tkaing the time and helping.

Comment: @mxm adding imaginary part is just to make the integral easier. Also, you know don't you that the integral you want to find is not the same when you add the imaginary part? After getting $0 = 0 + i0$ and looking at the real and its imaginary part you got $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{r\cos t} \cos(r\sin t + t)  dt = 0$$ and $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{r\cos t}\sin(r\sin t + t)  dt = 0.$$ One of the integral is the one you looking for.

Comment: makes sense. just for peace of mind, yes i know that adding the imaginary part changes the function we're integrating entirely, but there's always the possibility of some rule which i didn't know about which may allow you to do something. In this case the trick was available because the overall integral becomes zero and so we can just compare real and imaginary parts since the two don't interfere with each other.
Also, one last time. thank you for the help, it's helped alot.

Comment: For the record, could i not have used the fact that the upper bound is zero and so if i have a lower bound which is also zero, then by comparison the middle integral must also be zero?